# Dokku + Postgres : How to refresh a materialized view?

Tags: postgresql, cron, dokku

I am using Dokku with [dokku-postgres plugin](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-postgres/blob/master/subcommands/connect)

I am looking for a way to refresh my materialized views in a cron job.
I know that I can do
`dokku postgres:connect mydbinstance` to connect to the DB and then issue a `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW mymaterializedviewname` to have my view refreshed.

But I am looking for a single command (cron).
I could see [here](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-postgres/blob/master/subcommands/connect) that the plugin doesn't seem to support issuing such a command straight away.

How could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a command to do so. I ended up calling a shell script in cron, that triggers a psql function.

crontab :

```
0 0 * * * /home/scripts/refreshMaterializedViews.sh
```

refreshMaterializedViews.sh :

```
echo 'select RefreshAllMaterializedViews();' | dokku postgres:connect my-postgres-db
```

Where RefreshAllMaterializedViews() is a psql function to refresh all materialized views at once. I'll add it here for simplicity, but it's already all over S.O.

Psql function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RefreshAllMaterializedViews(schema_arg TEXT DEFAULT 'public')
RETURNS INT AS $$
DECLARE
    r RECORD;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Refreshing materialized view in schema %', schema_arg;
    FOR r IN SELECT matviewname FROM pg_matviews WHERE schemaname = schema_arg 
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'Refreshing %.%', schema_arg, r.matviewname;
        EXECUTE 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW ' || schema_arg || '.' || r.matviewname; 
    END LOOP;

    RETURN 1;
END 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note that this function doesn't support 'concurrently'. Which means it will lock your Materialized views during the refresh. For other solutions, please refer to [this S.O question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981600/how-to-refresh-all-materialized-views-in-postgresql-9-3-at-once)